# Android - background images take too much memory

Tags: android, memory, view, background

In my game I have 3 activities: Main menu -> Sub-menu -> Game screen. So when user is playing in the Game screen, first two activities are inactive, but not destroyed.

There is a nice background image in each layout. The image itself is quite small (40k), but on large screen (say Galaxy tablet), it takes up to several megs of memory.
After removing background from first two activities, memory usage in third activity falls from 18M to 13M!

Is there any way to keep backgrounds and to recover all this wasted memory?

Comment: I'm thinking for a temporary fix you can just have an onclick that removes the backgrounds from the first two when you're on that third page, then restores them on your way back.

Answer (score 5):

I have experienced a similar issue due to background images in layouts. The normal size of a memory allocation of an image should be height*width*4 bytes (in mode ARGB_8888, the default mode).

If you see and allocation of 18MB when showing an activity there must be some problem. Check if you are placing your background images in the drawable folder. In that case, the system must scale that image to the specific density of the screen, causing a big memory overhead.

Solutions:

1. Place a specific version of the background image in each drawable folder (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi...) so the system does not have to perfom any scaling process.
2. Place the background image in a special resource folder called "drawable-nodpi". The system won't try to scale images placed in this directory so only an streching process is carried out and the memory allocated will be the expected.

More information in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118005/android-background-image-memory-usage)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi , this is the solution I have searched for days. I have cached images, decode them, but none of them work except this. thanks a lot. Just add high resolution images to xxhdpi folder

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you finish the previous activities when starting the new activity (C). 
Then you can override the onKeyDown method in activity C to start the previous activity (B)

Comment: How can I finish B when starting C? I mean where in code should I put C.finish()?

Comment: No man..just call finish() before starting your intent for the new activity

Answer (score 3):

I think my problem is same to yours, this solution will help you.

[Why does the normal pictures allocated a lot of memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961096/why-does-the-normal-pictures-allocated-a-lot-of-memory-which-as-activity-backgro/17129758#17129758)

You can use /res/drawable-nodpi, the background pictrue only take half of the memory size.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to override onPause() or onStop() in your activity.  In there, you can release the background (by calling layout.setBackgroundDrawable(null))

Comment: You can always add an explicit call to System.gc().  Also make sure that your activity itself has no references anymore to the background image.