# Android OutOfMemoryException while changing ImageView Resource

Tags: android, exception, resources, imageview, out-of-memory

in my app i change the resource of an ImageView a lot of times with this method:

```
private void setIcon(int id, int imageSource) {
    ((ImageView)findViewById(id)).setBackgroundResource(imageSource);
}
```

After a while i get an OutOfMemoryException. Is there a better method to free the old resource (image) before i load the new one?

**EDIT**

```
private void setIcon(int id, int imageSource) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(id);
    Drawable bg= imageView.getBackground();

    if(bg != null && bg instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
         BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) bg;
         bitmapDrawable.getBitmap().recycle();
         if(D)Log.d(TAG, "recycled bitmap");
    }

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageSource);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

}
```

Comment: check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118005/android-background-image-memory-usage 
and check the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Before setting the new background, try to clear the memory for the old one, like this:

```
Drawable bg = image.getBackground();
if(bg != null && bg instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) bg;
    bitmapDrawable.getBitmap().recycle();
}
```

Do you have specific reasons to set the backgroundResource? Can't you simply use image.setResource(). That way it is easier to obtain the bitmap and recycle it.

**Edit**: if you only want one image (no overlays or something) than this is easier (and how it's supposed to be):

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(id);
image.setImageResource(imageSource);
```

Using bitmaps:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), id);
image.setImageBitmap(bm);
image.getDrawable(); // will return a BitmapDrawable
```

Comment: how do you build a BitmapDrawable from R.drawable.image ??

Comment: Updated my answer with BitmapDrawable example.

Comment: i edited my post. But i get OutOfMemoryExc faster than before. I never enter the block to recicle a bitmap. How it comes?