# Detemine correct image size to use for nodpi

Tags: android

I had different nine-patch images for different screens. However, I encountered an issue

[android drawable image takes lot of memory compared to its disk size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130848/android-drawable-image-takes-lot-of-memory-compared-to-its-disk-size)

So, I decided to use, for now, nodpi with hdpi image size.

Since, I have limited understanding, I was wondering what should be the image size I should put in drawable-nodpi folder.

Should I put hdpi images or xxxhdpi images? Or something else?

Please help me understand.

Comment: `Should I put hdpi images or xxxhdpi images? Or something else?` I'd try putting an xxxhdpi image into the `drawable-xxxhdpi` folder. That way it would be scaled **down**, preserving the quality (by using averaging  instead of pixellation).

Comment: But nodpi is **never scaled**. It's just the same big (or small - depending on the size of the image/s you put there in relation to the resolution and density of the device) blob, at any resolution and at any density. Is this you want?

Comment: my concern is I dont know how much image size/memory bloating will happen at runtime...and I will hit OOM errors. I discovered OOM while testing on emulator with 64MB memory??

Comment: You could try enlarging the heap size for your app. http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html

Comment: Did you try any strategy from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)?

Comment: yes...I did all of those...my issue is different here of image size bloating irrespective of how much memory app has.